# Upgraded Apache on Cpanel/WHM and subversion is not working

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

When trying to do a subversion command i get the following error after' upgrading Apache:

```
svnadmin: error while loading shared libraries: libaprutil-0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If i run : 
ldd 'which svn'
It show the following as not found:
    libaprutil-0.so.0 => not found

When I look to the folder it should be in i find that with the upgrade it has changed to:
libaprutil-1.so.0 which use to be libaprutil-0.so.0

Can I tell SVN to look for the new file name?

Comment: What distribution are you running?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of telling it where to find a new file name, it's a matter of having it compiled against the right version of the file to start with.

It looks like you need to upgrade some more software. Apache upgraded some libraries that other programs use, so you need versions of the other programs that use the new library versions.

I suggest starting by just doing an update of everything on the system using your distributions package manager although it should have already taken care of this for you. Maybe a full system update will help clean up the loose ends.

If you compiled and installed apache manually, you will also need to do so for any software that depends on it such as svn so that they are all compiled against the same libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is tricky since it neglects to tell you that what it really wants is the a particular architecture version of the lib from `apr-util` RPM.  This can be confirmed by running `strace svn` --in my case it revealed the lib64 version was missing. To solve it on an old CentOS 5.8 box, I did `sudo yum install apr-util` but for your distro, it might be different.  Note with bemusement that after that I had two versions of apr-util listed, with no readily apparent clue that one was 32-bit and the other 64-bit.